# How to segregate the whole code..please check

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi iam using this code here http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/pyNJ9/ I segregated the whole code in one page..means like the javascript under this tags

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

and the css code under

```
<script type="text/css"> 
 </script>
```

and used html code in html tags..but i am getting the textboxes also instead of single login href link.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.loginlink').click(function(e) {
    $('#loginform').dialog('open');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('#loginform').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="mytest.html" class="loginlink">Log In</a>

<div id="loginform">
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="username" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="password" type="password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: script type=css, are you sure?

Comment: Still i didnt able to get can you folks help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) as well.

The files the jsfiddle, you posted, uses are [CDN hosted script](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js) and [CDN hosted stylesheet](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css)

so change your code to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

and add in the head of your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" />
```

---

**UPDATE**

**Important** You need to wrap the code in `$(function(){ ... })` so that it runs after the DOM is loaded.

```
$(function(){
    $('a.loginlink').click(function(e) {
        $('#loginform').dialog('open');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $('#loginform').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false
    });
});
```

and to be sure that your jquery version is compatible with jquery UI version use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Full code at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/k6KjS/

Comment: Hi i have posted my updated code..can you please check and tell me where am missing..thank you